# Can I bring a big wooden sword as carry on in a plane?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

So I have this big wooden sword (4 feet high, 1 foot width) that I was hoping to bring on a short domestic flight (3 hours) from Perth to Adelaide.

The sword is not lethal or damaging. It is made of wood, has no pointy ends, and it is only  a part of a costume.

Specific question: Will I be allowed to take it with me?

General question: What are the limits on taking carry-on baggage aside from the N kg limit? Are there height/width limits?

I know that the answers may vary depending on the airport, but I'd love to hear your experiences/comments/insights still.

Comment: In the interest of clarifying the question `</flimsy excuse>`, I request a picture of the sword :)

Comment: @NickStauner, very well. Haha. Original post edited.

Comment: Whoa! I'm guessing that's gonna be a wicked costume...but...those ends *do* look a little pointy...I sure wouldn't worry about you hijacking anybody with it, but I'm guessing airport security is gonna feel differently...it is pretty bad@$$ after all.

Comment: Where would you put it if you can get it on-board? It looks like it could be wider than the overhead compartment.

Comment: I was thinking that I'd keep it by my side all the time, in a box, but now that I imagine it, I think it would be uncomfortable and weird.

Comment: @MarkGabriel Yeh, they won't let you do that for a number of reasons, the most practical one being that it would be unsecured should anything happen, even just turbulence; plus it would be an obstruction should an evacuation be necessary.

Comment: I think you'll avoid a lot of hassle at the airport if you carry this item as checked luggage. You can consider disassembling it and placing it in your bag, or else wrap it in bubble wrap and a sturdy outer layer and check it as a separate item.

Comment: I saw plenty of actual machetes, three or four feet long and SHARP, taken as carryon in the Pacific. The key was that they were swathed in newspaper. I think the more you wrap it up in layers of tape, bubble wrap, paper etc, the more likely it is to be allowed on, assuming the issue is it's swordness rather than its length

Comment: Funny story: I bought an actual broadsword in Spain and the airline would not allow me to put it in checked baggage and instead required me to carry it onto my US-bound flight in January 2001. They confiscated my dad's 5-inch blade pocket knife and allowed me to keep my broadsword. It was apparently an airport policy.

Comment: Wooden swords can be quite damaging indeed; the issue is the sword's mass and solidity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think any airline would allow you to take that sword as carry-on luggage into the cabin with you. However, you should be able to check it in as luggage (but it may be considered oversize luggage, which may be an extra fee). Just be sure to pack it well (you can find info about packing actual swords as luggage online, which may be helpful).

Answer (score 8):

The exact size limits for carry-on will depend on the airline, but your sword probably exceeds most airlines'. For example:

- Qantas's maximum dimension for a piece of carry-on luggage on a domestic flight is 115 cm (about 3' 9")
- Jetstar's is 56 cm (about 1' 10")

Comment: depending on the airline, and how bulky the item is, it may not even be considered part of the carry-on.  E.g. I've carried big umbrellas onto plans

Answer (score 2):

Often, regulations prohibit any kind of sporting equipment [which can be used as a weapon](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BatterUp) for carry-on, let alone sporting equipment from a combat sport.